# SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU9 - WFC Failover failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, update, clustering

I have updated my SQL Server 2016 on one of my Windows Failover Cluster nodes successfully.  When I attempted to failover one of my SQL instances onto the newly patched node, SQL Server service fails to come online.  These are the errors that I'm seeing:

> Error: 3930, Severity: 16, State: 1. The current transaction cannot
>   be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file.
>   Roll back the transaction.
>
> Error: 912, Severity: 21, State: 2. Script level upgrade for database
>   'master' failed because upgrade step 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered
>   error 3930, state 1, severity 16. This is a serious error condition
>   which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be
>   taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master'
>   database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from
>   starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the
>   appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the
>   script upgrade steps run to completion.
>
> Error: 3417, Severity: 21, State: 3. Cannot recover the master
>   database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full
>   backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to
>   rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.

I'm also seeing some `Failed to verify the Authenticode signature...`
 messages.

The only way I was able to successfully failover the SQL instance was
 by adding Trace Flag 902.  I ran the msdb110_upgrade.sql script and it
 ran fine (although it did take 3 minutes).  This is the result:

> TSQL  Transact-SQL
>   Subsystem [Internal]  [Internal]  [Internal]  [Internal]  [Internal]  480 1
>   CmdExec   Command-Line
>   Subsystem SQLCMDSS.DLL    NULL    CmdExecStart    CmdEvent    CmdExecStop 240 3
>   Snapshot  Replication Snapshot Subsystem  SQLREPSS.DLL    C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\COM\SNAPSHOT.EXE   ReplStart   ReplEvent   ReplStop    2400    4
>   LogReader Replication Transaction-Log Reader
>   Subsystem SQLREPSS.DLL    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\COM\logread.exe    ReplStart   ReplEvent   ReplStop    600 5
>   Distribution  Replication Distribution
>   Subsystem SQLREPSS.DLL    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\COM\DISTRIB.EXE    ReplStart   ReplEvent   ReplStop    2400    6
>   Merge Replication Merge Subsystem SQLREPSS.DLL    C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\COM\REPLMERG.EXE   ReplStart   ReplEvent   ReplStop    2400    7
>   QueueReader   Replication Transaction Queue Reader
>   Subsystem SQLREPSS.dll    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\COM\qrdrsvc.exe    ReplStart   ReplEvent   ReplStop    2400    8
>   ANALYSISQUERY Analysis query
>   subsystem SQLOLAPSS.DLL   NULL    OlapStart   OlapQueryEvent  OlapStop    2400    9
>   ANALYSISCOMMAND   Analysis command
>   subsystem SQLOLAPSS.DLL   NULL    OlapStart   OlapCommandEvent    OlapStop    2400    10
>   SSIS  SSIS package execution subsystem    SQLDTSSS.DLL    C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe    DtsStart    DtsEvent    DtsStop 2400    11
>   PowerShell    PowerShell Subsystem    SQLPOWERSHELLSS.DLL C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn\SQLPS.exe   PowerShellStart PowerShellEvent PowerShellStop  2   12

Each time, I would `NET STOP` the SQL service and `NET START` without Trace Flag 902, but the SQL service would still fail.

Has anyone run into this and found a solution?

Edit 1: I was able to successfully fail over another SQL instance on to the recently patched node. It's absolutely baffling why this one particular SQL instance isn't coming online with T902. I did notice another thing. I see a `Failed to update database "DB" because the database is read-only and Error executing sp_vupgrade_replication`

Edit 2: I was originally on version 13.0.5337.0 and updated to 13.0.5479.

Edit 3: I was just informed that Microsoft issued a warning for this CU9 (however, I don't believe this is causing the issue I'm facing):
Important
There is an uninstall issue with SQL16 SP2 CU9. The payload in CU9 is fine, but if you have not already installed CU9, it is recommended that you wait for the upcoming expedited SQL16 SP2 CU10 release.